# Prevent custom error bars from going into negative values

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have some bar charts with custom value error bars. I adjusted the values sothat I would add the 1/2 of the value into the negative and 1/2 into the positive direction (basically to make the error bar half run through the actual bar of the graph and the other half stick out above).

However, a few of my error bar values are so high that they cross the x-axis and go into the negative. Ideally, I would like to adjust those exact error bars (and, if possible, no other bars in the row of data). I'd like to have them moved upwards sothat they just don't cross the x-axis, but instead stick out above the actual bar a little more.

Does anyone know any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have the values in column A and the errors (half values) in column B. Use this function in C:

```
=IF(B1-A1>0,A1,B1)
```

and this in D:

```
=IF(B1-A1>0,2*B1-A1,B1)
```

Then use the values from C as the negative errors and the values from D as the positive errors.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!